# How to sum a range of numbers in Excel while ignoring percentages?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXL1Q.jpg)Hi i want to be able to add a range of numbers but ignore percentages that are in the same range. for example

```
10
10
10%
10
= 30 total
```

Functions I have tried are `countif()`, `Sumif()`, `aggregate()` can anyone help please?

Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya This will fail if OP have `100%` in any cell.

Comment: I have posted picture can you see @MayukhBhattacharya? Formula did not seem to work. Is this cause there is also text in this column?

Comment: Could you please replace your image by a toy (minimal) example [formatted as a table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/2057969)?

Answer (score 2):

If you chance to have `100%` or above then use-

```
=SUM(FILTER(A1:A4,BYROW(A1:A4,LAMBDA(x,CELL("format",x)<>"P0"))))
```

`CELL()` function format `P0` indicate percentage.

[image]

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Hmm, if it is not `M365` then we have to go with array approach with combination of few formulas.

Comment: I suggest generalizing a bit by just looking for `P` as the successive characters can change depending on number of decimal places, how negative values are displayed and the use of parentheses.

Comment: Thanks @ron. how would i do this?

Comment: @LukeMartin It is a minor change in the formula presented by `Harun24hr` in this Answer. You should be able to make the change after you understand the formula.