# How to sum and/subtract a range of numbers in Excel while ignoring percentages?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I want to be able to sum and/subtract a range of numbers but ignoring +/- percentages that are in the same range too.

[image]

I have tried following the formula in this thread, [How to sum a range of numbers in Excel while ignoring percentages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76404632/how-to-sum-a-range-of-numbers-in-excel-while-ignoring-percentages) , but it is not giving me the correct answer of just (32,870) without any decimal differences. What am i doing wrong in the formula?

Answer (score 2):

It should be <kbd>P2</kbd> and not <kbd>PO%</kbd> as shown in your screenshot.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A10</kbd>

```
=SUM(FILTER(A1:A8,BYROW(A1:A8,LAMBDA(x,CELL("format",x)<>"P2"))))
```

---

**Notes:** <kbd>CELL()</kbd> function format <kbd>P0</kbd> indicate percentage format of <kbd>0%</kbd> while <kbd>P2</kbd> is <kbd>0.00%</kbd> as per **[Microsoft Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf)**

---

**Caveat :** The above solution wont work if the decimal places are more than 2, however, you can try this approach as well using <kbd>ISNA( )</kbd> & <kbd>TEXTAFTER( )</kbd>

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A10</kbd>

```
=SUM(FILTER(A1:A8,ISNA(TEXTAFTER(A1:A8,"."))))
```

---

Look at this screenshot below to understand how this formula is working:

[image]

Refer columns <kbd>C</kbd> , <kbd>D</kbd> & <kbd>E</kbd> and the formulas used.

---

Here is another screenshot, with some test cases.

[image]

---

Refer the cell <kbd>C6</kbd> even if the percentage is more than `100%` still it works. However this approach works but it may not work if there is a decimal value for numbers.

---

### **Edit :**

**Comment by OP:**

> *Thank you so much for the answer. it is working perfectly fine. However, I do have another question. What will happen if my numbers
> now have values after the decimal point, like a .5, or .6 or even .9,
> how can these amounts also be included in the summation or
> subtraction? For example, 18,000 now becomes 18,000.05, and the 14,870
> becomes 14,870.90?*

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A10</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, --TEXTBEFORE(A1:A8,".")<>0,
     b, ISNA(a),
     SUM(FILTER(A1:A8,ISNUMBER(1/(a+b)))))
```

---

Or,

• in cell <kbd>B10</kbd>

```
=SUM(FILTER(A1:A8,
  MMULT(N(BYROW(A1:A8,LAMBDA(x,CELL("format",x)))<>{"P4","P2","P0"}),{1;1;1})=3))
```

---

Or,

• in cell <kbd>C10</kbd>

```
=SUM(FILTER(A1:A8,N(BYROW(A1:A8,LAMBDA(x,CELL("format",x)))=",4")))
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. it is working perfectly fine. However, I do have another question.

What will happen if my numbers now have values after the decimal point, like a .5, or .6 or even .9, how can these amounts also be included in the summation or subtraction?

For example, 18,000 now becomes 18,000.05, and the 14,870 becomes 14,870.90?

Comment: @KudaMagaya hi, i have few questions, please confirm, will the percentages be always less than `100%`?

Comment: Hi @Mayukh Bhattacharya, not all the time. They will be negative, at times positive, above 100% and at times below as well, depending on the case.

Comment: Then post screenshot accordingly which makes sense with your comments

Comment: I have tried the formula, and it is working perfectly well, IF the row cells being summed up do not exceed 8. I have tried it in a column with 50 cells, and it's no longer working. How best can we further customize the formula to get it to work?

Comment: Please update your post with relevant information.

Comment: I have 3 different scenarios as per the screen shot below, using the 3 different formulas given above, and the 4th entry, which is the control, whereby I have manually added across the rows. However, there are differing results.

When using the given formulas, some of their results match to the control, and some don't. Of the ones which match to the control, that formula is not match across all 3 examples.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16vBuXgn0LrajbJSECYKZmsHtrt9t8iHZ/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113753504467498481589&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @KudaMagaya if you have a data setup as shown in the excel then why not use this formula. `=SUMPRODUCT((MOD((COLUMN(B2:X2)-2),3)=0)*B2:X2)` let me know and here is the `Excel` Sorry for the delay i didnt got the notifications. Here is `Excel` **[File](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckHrbi9eDeknJI3Wn?e=DcPT4s)** and **[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/gallery/qNLELaO)**